# Undo use of F5 which added a thick black line around fields and buttons

Tags: macos, keyboard

I have searched the user manuals and can find no information on using F keys and how to cancel a command I have done.
macOS 10.8.5

I foolishly followed some advice and used F5 button for something. Now there is a permanent open field on all windows and Excel won't let me input into individual fields.

I don't remember what I did, why I did it, and don't know how to undo it. Thick black line flashes round a field box, or any button.

How can I undo this action?

Comment: Is this the same question you posted a few minutes ago [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/321394/88313)?

Comment: If it is, he should combine them here and delete the one on hold

Comment: Don't repost your questions, edit your question to improve it. I have removed the previous question.

Comment: Thanks grgside and bjbk - I couldn't find a way to edit it which was acceptable to remove the hold, so asked a different question! Thanks for merging them.

Answer (score 6):

You appear to have enabled the Accessibility shortcut.

To toggle it back off, <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>

[image: Accessibility settings]

Answer (score 1):

As @bjbk indicates correctly, you have accidentally enabled accessibility tools, and need to de-activate them if they are unneeded or obstructive.

You *can* go up to menu bar at the top of the screen, to the **Apple** menu, click on the **Apple icon** at the extreme left of that menu bar, go to **System Preferences**, **Accessibilty**, and manually turn it off there, or as @bjbk indicated in their answer, you can use the Shortcut Key to toggle the state, which is now ON to OFF - 
click on <kbd>option</kbd> **+** <kbd>command</kbd> **+** <kbd>F5</kbd>  to accomplish this.

Comment: Thankyou - This seems to be my problem, but opt+commnad+F5 is not working and I don't have an Accessibility option in my System Preferences (OS 10.5.8)

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH - I have found a 'voice-over' toggle in the Universal Access Preferences which was on and switched it off. It only needs cmd+F5 on my OS